# Relational Algebra - Divide

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, relational-algebra

If I have the following tables and I perform R1/R2 in relational algebra, would the result be a table with A values 1 and 3? I am a bit confused as I know 3 would be a result as it contains both 5 and 1, but the result 1 has additional values for B aside from the matching ones so would this also be included and why?

```
     R1          R2
    +---+---+   +---+
    | A | B |   | B |
    |---|---|   |---|
    | 1 | 1 |   | 5 |
    | 1 | 2 |   | 1 |
    | 1 | 3 |   +---+
    | 1 | 4 |
    | 2 | 3 |
    | 2 | 4 |
    | 3 | 5 |
    | 3 | 1 |
    | 1 | 5 |
    | 5 | 7 |
    | 5 | 8 |
    +---+---+
```

Comment: Depends whether you want Division with a Remainder or Exact Division. See [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). AFAIK division with a remainder is [the usual interpretation](http://coronet.iicm.tugraz.at/Dbase1/scripts/rdbh06.htm) in relational algebra.

Comment: @MartinSmith, that is what I had thought, that relational algebra operates division with a remainder. Just wanted to check!

Answer (score 3):

In relational databases Divide is defined as: 
R1(Y,X) DIVIDE R2(X) = R1[Y] MINUS ((R1[Y] TIMES R2) MINUS R1)[Y]

remember that R1[Y] is another form of "PROJECT R1 over Y".
so the result is {1,3}